# Alternatives to "yet on the other hand"

Tags: phrases, expressions, discourse-markers

I just read "yet on the other hand" in a published research article and it seemed off to me. Is it just me? Is there a better alternative?

Specifically: The *yet* seems to be redundant to *on the other hand* and doesn't appear in the dictionary or typical examples I've seen that use *on the other hand*. Is it necessarily  redundant? Is there a valid use case where *yet* is added to *on the other hand*?

Comment: However, what would a dictionary tell you about "on the other hand"? Please also check the English Language Learner's SE website or show your work :).

Comment: @SrJoven, the "yet..." part before "... on the other hand" is a part of what seems off and isn't in the dictionary or typical examples I've seen.

Comment: That's often enough done. Maybe the *yet* didn't work in the context of the preceding and following text, which would make it seem off, but it certainly is okay in itself.

Comment: @JonHanna On one hand, some researchers (e.g., Lee, 2000) recommend that MLM only be used when the ICC is greater than .10, indicating that 10% of the variability is between psychotherapists. Yet on the other hand, Roberts (2007) found that even when the ICC is near zero for a model with no predictors, “group dependence may still exist depending on the nature of the covariates introduced into the model” (p. 15), thus indicating a need for MLM with very small ICCs.
http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/pst/49/2/152/

Comment: The "yet" seems redundant. "On the other hand" seems sufficient.

Comment: The *yet* stresses the difference. I agree it's redundant and would personally recommending the writer cut it, but it's not incorrect to the point of being strange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following would flow better without the use of "yet on the other hand" (from your provided example):

> <s>On one hand,</s> **S**ome researchers (e.g., Lee, 2000) recommend that MLM
>   only be used when the ICC is greater than .10, indicating that 10% of
>   the variability is between psychotherapists. Yet <s>on the other hand,</s> **in 2007,**
>   Roberts <s>(2007)</s> found that even when the ICC is near zero for a model
>   with no predictors, “group dependence may still exist depending on the
>   nature of the covariates introduced into the model” (p. 15), thus
>   indicating a need for MLM with very small ICCs.

The following answer may also provide some insights: 
[Academic way of saying "On the other hand"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/50616/academic-way-of-saying-on-the-other-hand)

Answer (score 0):

A word to preface (on the other hand): While on the other hand is how I've always heard it. The other way it can be said is "Yet at the same time..." ♥

Answer (score 0):

Try the word 'however', and 'yet' and 'on the other hand' are redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Searching [Google Ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=on+the+other+hand%2C(yet+on+the+other+hand*1000)&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Con%20the%20other%20hand%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%28yet%20on%20the%20other%20hand%20%2A%201000%29%3B%2Cc0) indicates that *on the other hand* is currently roughly 1000 times more popular in books than *yet on the other hand*.

Searching [Google Books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22yet+on+the+other+hand%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl) proper seems to indicate some consistent usage of *yet on the other hand* where distinction in opposition is presented.

Arguably one's usage in literature does not necessarily imply correctness of use, but it does give credence to multiple authors' reliance on said usage, awkward or not, and alternative available or not, this is the structure chosen for this publication circumstance.